# Can't figure out this error when trying to connect mysql from netbean

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect mysql from netbean but it got this error.
My user and password is "root"

[image]

[image]

Please help me with this. Many thanks for that

Comment: You have to show some sample code so that we can replicate the code.

Comment: Made pictures visible.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line?